# Does K and its Hilbert class field have same conductor?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be an abelian number field and $H(K)$ be the Hilbert class field of $K.$

**Definition:** (conductor of a abelian number field) Let $K$ be a number field with the abelian Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}.$ The conductor $n$ is the smallest even number such that $K\subset Q(\zeta_n).$

Will $K$ and $H(K)$ have the same conductor? Assuming that $H(K)$ is abelian over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802416/does-a-number-field-and-its-hilbert-class-field-have-same-conductors

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Under the conditions you describe, $H(K)$ agrees with the genus class field $G(K)$, which has the same conductor as $K$. For an explicit description of $G(K)$, see [Xianke Zhang's paper from 1985](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2045220?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).